# Automatic Macro for every sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a method which is just formattong the excel sheet but the problem is i have 14 sheets and auto_open method is working in a Sheet1 only?

is there any way to a run a method which will run for everysheet automatically when someone just open the excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A for loop for all the sheets on workbook in Auto_open method.

Answer (score 0):

The best would be to create function or a sub which is called by every "OnOpen" events of your sheets.